# How to restart celery using supervisord?

Tags: celery

I have celery running in production environment. Whenever I change the code and restart the celery worker, it takes 15-20 minutes just to receive tasks. A lot of tasks gets registered as follow.

`[2020-06-22 04:12:10,831: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.tasks.task1[61aa7bf0-6b86-4d18-8faa-7354fda1f5e7]  ETA:[2020-06-22 23:37:16.413708+05:30]`

Basically these are tasks that needs to be run at a later time, but it does slow down the complete restart of celery process as there are a lot of task to be run at later time. Is there a way to avoid this?

One thing that has worked for me in case of prefork is sending the `HUP` signal to child worker processes, but what will I do in case of `eventlet`. Also, is it even the right way to do it that is by sending `HUP` signal to child processes?

My `supervisord` celery config is as follow:

```
[program:celeryd]
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.settings.celery
command=venv/bin/celery -A proj.celery worker -l info
stdout_logfile=/var/logs/celeryd_out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/logs/celeryd_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=3
stopwaitsecs=600
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=KILL
```